# Delphi 2010: Read text from Word 2010 document

Tags: delphi, ms-word, delphi-2010

I have an application that inserts information into a Word Document from a database.

I have had a request that the information in the Word Document can be changed at a later date.

In order to achieve that I have written a macro that launches my application which can then read the bookmarks in the document to find the sections in the document.

I am stumbling with being able to read the text that has been set at a particular bookmark.

I can set the text of the bookmark using the following code:

```
bookmark := 'PersonName';
R := WordDoc.Bookmarks.Item(bookmark).Range;
R.Text := "Joe Bloggs";
```

Part of the issue is that the bookmark is a not set as a block of text - this ensures that when the text is set the Bookmark persists - which means that at least I can set the range at second run.

Try as I might I cannot find a way of getting any result back for either

```
R.text
```

or

```
WordApp.Selection.Text
```

when using the bookmark to set the starting point.

Any suggestions?

Inserting text at the second run works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try readding the bookmark after setting the text:

```
Bookmark := 'PersonName';
R := WordDoc.Bookmarks.Item(Bookmark).Range;
R.Text := 'Joe Bloggs';
WordDoc.Bookmarks.Add(Bookmark, R);
```

[See here for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad6ks7k0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Because the bookmark is set as a single char the R.Text returns an empty string.  If the bookmark is expanded to cover some dummy text the bookmark is erased on insertion...